# Model chaining/"bridging" to read Multi-level structure as planar

Tags: java, wicket

Suppose the following multi-level structure:

```
class Habitation {
  private House house;
  private List<Habitant> habitants;
}
```

This object needs to displayed in planar form for each habitant in a ListView (that's why multi level object need to be represented in planar form) like this:

```
| habitant.name | house.address |
|      ...      |      ...      |
```

I thought it would be a proper thing to do: to create a "bridging"/chaining object like this:

```
class PlanarHabitant {
  private IModel<House> house;
  private IModel<Habitant> habitant;
}
```

This bridging  object is created from `Habitation` object like this:

```
//Habitation.expand()
public List<PlanarHabitant> expand() {
  List<PlanarHabitant> res = new ArrayList<PlanarHabitant>();
  for (Habitant habitant : this.habitants) {
    PlanarHabitant ph = new PlanarHabitant();
    ph.setHouse(Model.of(this.house));
    ph.setHabitant(Model.of(habitant));
    res.add(ph);
  }
  return res;
}
```

And this data is displayed in ListView. It is done like this:

```
final IModel<List<PlanarHabitant>> model = (IModel<List<PlanarHabitant>>) this.getDefaultModel();//model assigned is Model.ofList(Habitation.expand())

    this.importList = new ListView<PlanarHabitant>("habitants",  model) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(final ListItem<PlanarHabitant> item) {
            item.add(new Label("cn", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "habitant.name")));
        }
    };
```

The problem is that model for label always gives exception that Field does not exist.

I tried to assign `CompoundPropertyModel` (and others) to `PlanarHabitant` and different path expressions but nothing works.

Am I just using wrong combinations of models and path expressions or is it completely wrong way to do?

The reason that multi-level structure should not be converted to planar for is that it needs to be saved and duplications of House in `PlanarHabitant` will create duplications in DB which should not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're constructing a hierarchy of nested objects with models in between:

```
Model
 ⟶ List<PlanarHabitant>
     ⟶* PlanarHabitant
          ⟶ Model<House>
              ⟶ House
          ⟶ Model<Habitant>
              ⟶ Habitant
```

Each `ListView`'s item has a `Model<PlanarHabitant>` (which is created automagically for you), thus your property expression would have to be `"habitant.object.name"`.

Of course it would be better to just skip the nested model:

```
class PlanarHabitant {
  private House house;
  private Habitant habitant;
}
```

Usually when you see non-Wicket objects (no component nor model itself) holding a reference to a model, there's something going wrong.

Comment: Indeed it is, thank you. My worries was that my `Habitation` and `Habitant` objects contain `boolean` field and I thought it will just create a copy. But it did not happen (probably my knowledge is mislead).

And thank you for advice.